Font missing error when generating PDF in Next.js API route but working in standalone Node.js
I am working on a **Next.js project **where I need to generate a PDF file upon hitting an API endpoint. I am encountering a "Helvitica font missing" error when I try to generate the PDF within Next.js, although the same code works perfectly when executed in a standalone Node.js environment using the node command. I'm using pdfkit npm library.
*The Error - An unexpected error occurred Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'C:\Users....next\server\vendor-chunks\data\Helvetica.afm'
*
API route - /api/generate

"use server"
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { createPdf } from "@/pdfkitGenerator";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
try {
const { username } = await req.json();

    const text = "BODY";
    
    const pdfName = await createPdf("HEADING", text, username);
    
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        success: true,
        pdfName,
      },
      {
        status: 200,
      }
    );

} catch (error) {
console.log("An unexpected error occurred", error);

    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        success: false,
        message: "Internal Server Error",
      },
      {
        status: 500,
      }
    );

}
}

pdfGenerator.js file`

"use server"
import fs from "fs";
import fsPromises from "fs/promises";
import PDFDocument from "pdfkit";
import path from "path";

const \__dirname = path.resolve();

export async function createPdf(title, text, username) {
const fileName = username + Date.now();
const documentsPath = path.join(\__dirname, "assets", "documents");

try {
await fsPromises.access(documentsPath);
} catch (error) {
// Directory does not exist, create it
await fsPromises.mkdir(documentsPath, { recursive: true });
}

const pdfPath = path.join(documentsPath, `${fileName}.pdf`);

const doc = new PDFDocument({
margins: {
top: 36,
bottom: 36,
left: 36,
right: 36,
},
});

doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pdfPath));

doc.fontSize(25).text(title, { align: "center" });

doc.moveDown();

text.split("\\n").forEach((line) =\> {
doc.fontSize(12).text(line);
doc.moveDown();
});

doc.end();

return fileName;
}



@KJ It's all messed up dude, after a lot of digging found out that the server side nextjs can't handle pdfkit on a route, so I build a nodejs backend api instead and it worked
